# Miranda's Proposition 1.11 pag. 63

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two complex tori given by lattices $L$ and $M$ respectively. Then any holomorphic map $F: X \mapsto Y$ is induced by a linear map $G: \mathbb{C} \mapsto \mathbb{C}$ of the form $G(z)=\gamma z + a$ where $\gamma$ is a constant such that $\gamma L \subset M$. The constant $a$ may be taken to be zero if and only if $F$ sends $0$ to $0$; in this case the map $F$ is a homomorphism of groups. The holomorphic map $F$ is an isomorphism if and only if $\gamma L=M$. In general, the degree of $F$ is the index $|M/\gamma L|$ of $\gamma L$ inside $M$.

In order to proof this last statement, I consider the commutative diagram 
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{C} @>G>> \mathbb{C} \\
@V{\pi}VV @VV{\pi}V \\
X@>>F> Y \\
\end{CD} \\
$$
and I study $F^{-1}(z+M)$. Now I note that $F^{-1}=\pi \circ G^{-1} \circ \pi^{-1}$. After some calculation I obtain $F^{-1}(z+M)=z+\gamma L$ or $F^{-1}(z+M)=z+L$. But I don't obtain the result of my thesis. What's wrong?

Comment: It seems that for commutative diagram to render you need to add '\require{AMScd}'. See [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2324/how-to-draw-a-commutative-diagram).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that $F$ isn't invertible, so you have to be careful with all thos $-1$'s you wrote. It is easy to see that $\deg F=|\ker F|$, and 
$$\ker F=\{z+L\in \mathbb{C}/L:\gamma z+M=0\}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\gamma z\in M\}\mbox{ mod }L=(\frac{1}{\gamma}M)/L\simeq M/\gamma L.$$
Taking the order of this group gives you what you want.